# Preventing text wrapping between header and paragraph

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a layout with a floated image and a series of h2s and paragraphs that wrap around it. What I want to do is prevent wrapping around the bottom of the image between a header and its associated paragraph.

Instead of:

```
---------------
|             |  HEADER 1
|    IMAGE    |  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
|             |  consectetur adipiscing elit.
|             |  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
|             |
---------------  HEADER 2
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
```

I want:

```
---------------
|             |  HEADER 1
|    IMAGE    |  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
|             |  consectetur adipiscing elit.
|             |  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
|             |
---------------  
HEADER 2
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

The site is responsive, so where the wrap occurs will vary (and I can't just clear the second header.)

Here's what it should look like at a larger width:

```
---------------
|             |  HEADER 1
|    IMAGE    |  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
|             |  elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
|             |  
|             |  HEADER 2
---------------  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

Here's some sample code:

```css
img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
<h2>Some Heading</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>

<h2>Some Other heading</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrbh/jm87ghwn/1/)

I've tried putting the headers/paragraph pairs in sections set to overflow: hidden, e.g.

```css
img {
  float: left;
}
section {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
<section>
  <h2>Some Heading</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
</section>

<section>
  <h2>Some Other heading</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
</section>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrbh/9wbttdjc/1/)

But that's not exactly what I'm looking for either. Doing that keeps the entire paragraph from wrapping, but I want the wrap to happen when it hits in the middle of a paragraph, just not between the header and the paragraph - e.g.

```
---------------
|             |  HEADER 1
|    IMAGE    |  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
|             |  elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
|             |  
|             |  HEADER 2
---------------  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
                 elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
                 elit.
```

Comment: Could you provide the actual code by chance? That will help us out tremendously! Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just added some code and clarified my question a bit, hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
  <div class="clear"></div>
```

before your second header.

With

```
div.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

But since you are not providing any code, it is difficult to provide an accurate answer.

In general, check out `clear` and `clearfix`. Those should help you "resolve" your style after using float.

Actually, [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_class-clear) provides a very basic example of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Clearing DIVs, as suggested above, are frowned upon and not considered a "best practice."

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify and add sample code. Clearing the second header won't work, as the site is responsive and a some widths I *want* the header and paragraph to wrap around the image.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest option its to wrap the header, text combos (with or without an image in a DIV or related element.

```css
.group {
  clear: left;
}
.group > img {
  float: left;
}
.group-text {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<article class="group">

  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <div class="group-text">
    <h2>Some Heading</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. 
      Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor.
    </p>  
  </div>

</article>

<article class="group">

  <h2>Some Other heading</h2>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor.
  </p>

</article>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lr874gjd/1/)

You could also do this without wrapping every heading and text pair that doesn't have an image. We clear the float of the `.group` wrapper. So they do not *"hang"* on the image before it like you have illustrated.

For the headings (h2) inside a wrapper we need to undo the clearing that we applied to all headings (h2), otherwise they clear the float of the image and would appear below it.

```css
h2, .group {
  clear: left;
}
.group > img {
  float: left;
}
.group-text {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.group-text h2 {
  clear: none;
}
```

```html
<article class="group">

  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <div class="group-text">
    <h2>Some Heading</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. 
      Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor.
    </p>  
  </div>

</article>

<h2>Some Other heading</h2>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor.
</p>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lr874gjd/)

Note that `.group-text { overflow: hidden; }` causes the text to not wrap the image. If you would prefer wrapping, remove that property.

Comment: Thanks! The page is responsive, so how text flows around the image will vary - I can't really clear any individual h2s then.

Comment: the problem with wrapping the pairs in a div with overflow:hidden is that the text of the paragraph won't wrap around the image, the. I only want to prevent text-wrapping between th header and the paragraph - the rest of the paragraph should wrap as normal.

Comment: I've edited the original question to clarify and provide sample code.

Comment: Based on your latest update what you're asking isn't going to be one simple set of CSS. It's going to require media queries. Having the header and text clear in one instance and not another will require you to figure out where those breakpoints are in your design and set the appropriate styling. Whether that's clearing the header at one point and not clearing it after another breakpoint.

Comment: That sounds messy! Here's a link to the actual page in question, if that helps: http://hartness.vsc.edu/ccv/about/staff/test/larraby-fellows/ (Currently it has each question/answer wrapped in a section with overflow:hidden) Maybe the easiest answer is just to change the design and float the image right instead of left.

Comment: It might sound messy but you're being very particular in your request. Sometimes you want the header to "snag" other times you don't. Take a look at espn.go.com. They have plenty of media queries going on to handle their layout.